# bone spine004 cannot connect chain bone position is disjoint. incorrect armature for type chain_rigs

Tags: animation, rigging

Using rigify when generating the rig I get this error message Does someone know how I can fix this I don´t want to start it all over :_C[image]

Comment: I had the same error with 2.83 version. I tried it again in 2.81 and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

I went to Bone Properties for Spine004.

'Inherit Rotation' was checked,  I unchecked it.
...no more Error

Answer (score 1):

Select the spine004 bone in edit mode, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  and select *Disconnect Bone*.

Answer (score 1):

The same things occurred to me. I used Blender 2.90. What worked for me: delete the problematic bone. Select Spine 3 and 5 (the spheres at the end of missing spine 4) and click F. Rename the bone to Spine 4. Save, go back to object mode, and try rigifying again. It should work now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the original 2.80 Blender build to avoid this error. It doesn't work in 2.83 nor 2.82, and not even in the final 2.81 version (although some interim 2.81 builds appear to be ok).

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Here's what I did to fix it & successfully generate a rig:

- Go into edit mode.
- Select the lower joint spine004 (around neck area).
- While this above is selected, hold the Shift key & select the top joint of Spine003.
- While both joints are now selected (highlighted), click the F key to create a new bone that will connect your selection OR right-click to open up a menu & select "Fill Between Joints".

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the problematic bone, then selected the bones on both sides of the empty space, then pressed <kbd>F</kbd>.